# DatePickerDialog closes when rotating from landscape/portrait

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I'm having problem width DatePickerDialog, because when it's opened and I turn the screen (landscape/portrait) the dialog stops.
Now I'm trying to save the state of a dialog in a Bundle, but I don't really know how :/

The code:

```
public class ActivityNeki extends Activity {
    private int datY, datM, datD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){ setTheData(); writeTheData(); }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("izY", datY);
        outState.putInt("izM", datM);
        outState.putInt("izD", datD);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        datY = savedInstanceState.getInt("izY");
        datM = savedInstanceState.getInt("izM");
        datD = savedInstanceState.getInt("izD");
        writeTheData();
    }

    public void onClickOpenDPD(View view) {    // the method that is caled from XML onClick
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {
                datY = y; datM = m; datD = d;
                writeTheData();
            }
        }, datY, datM, datD);
        dpd.show();
    }

    public void setTheData(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        datY = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        datM = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        datD = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    public void writeTheData(){
        // writes the data in a txtView
    }

}
```

**So if anyon have any idea how to do this, I will apriceate it !**

Thanks in advance :)

---

**The working solution:** (Big tnx to Taig)

```
public class ActivityNeki extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
    * the rest of the code
    * is the same...
    * I only edited this method:
    */
    public void onClickOpenDPD(View view) {    // the method that is caled from XML onClick
        class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
            @Override public void onDestroyView() {
                if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance()) getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
                super.onDestroyView();
            }
            @Override public void onCreate(Bundle state) { super.onCreate(state);
                setRetainInstance(true);
            }
            @Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle state) {
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog( getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {
                        datY = y; datM = m; datD = d;
                        writeTheData();
                } }, datY, datM, datD);
                return dpd;
            }
        }
        newDF = new MyDialogFragment();
        newDF.show( getSupportFragmentManager(), null );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using DialogFragments if that is an option for you.

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle state ) {
        super.onCreate( state );

        setRetainInstance( true );
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog( Bundle state ) {
        return new DatePickerDialog( ... );
    }
}
```

In your activity you can then launch the dialog by calling `new MyDialogFragment().show( getSupportFragmentManager(), null )`. The Dialog will reopen and you don't have to persist the current selection on orientation change by yourself!

Comment: tnx for the answer :) now it works at least without errors in LogCat.. But when I turn the screen, the Dialog still closes :/ any ideas ?
Tnx again ! :)

Comment: Could you try to define the fragment as a static class out of the method scope (e.g. in an own file), please? Remove the onDataSet code for that, because it will stop working without the class reference.

Comment: Can't create a static class in another file... But I transferred the class in another file and it still close on rotation and if I create a static class in this activity it closes anyway :/

Comment: Ouch, there is an issue with DialogFragments which I long forgot about and fixed somewhere deep in my tools library. You might wanna give http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433397/android-dialogfragment-disappears-after-orientation-change a try!

Comment: Ok now that worked ! :D I will accept your answer, because it helped me a lot and with your help the datapicker now works !!! :)
Tenx again :)